# Update android app java code without reinstall an APK

Tags: android

I have jar library that developers can integrate in their Android app. The problem is that developers update my library very rarely, for example once in a year. For that time may not work due to new Android version, or I found critical bug after integration in my library.

Is it possible that library can update itself without update an APK?
Something like using downloadable jar or dex file.

Comment: "The problem is that developers update my library very rarely, for example once in a year" -- that would seem to be the choice of the developers of the apps using the library, not you.

Comment: What if your update changes your library's public API, or introduces a breaking change? Unless your library has a *very* good reason that it *absolutely needs to* be up-to-date, updating without giving the end developer control over the process is unlikely to go over well. I know I wouldn't use such a library.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, but I loose money because of this. My library becomes broken, and developers does not  want to update it - because it not working, and not working it because they don't want to update it.

Comment: Have you talked to the developers about this? If they don't want to update your library, there is likely an underlying reason and you should address that issue.

Comment: @Tanis.7x yes, I talked with developers about this, but they do not want to spent time/money to update APK at all. Or it can be some big company and they update theur APK according to schedule every 6 month. Moreover, my library is in public access and do not know all it users.

Comment: As far as I know, you can do this. A reknowned app developer used to do that as well but Google discourages it. Besides it can also cause breaking changes if the app and the library isn't controlled by only one entity.

Comment: @UmerFarooq What renowned app developer?